# concatenation setState with dynamic key in react using es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is how I use dynamic setState but what if I want to prefix the state name?

```
handleChange(field, value) {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
}

<input
  onChange={e => this.handleChange('fname', e.target.value)}
/>
<input
  onChange={e => this.handleChange('lname', e.target.value)}
/>
```

Like I want to produce `this.state.my_fname` and `this.state.my_lname`.

Comment: in `handleChange` first param `field` is a string. you can concat like `{ ['my' + field]: value }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this achieve what you're after?

```
handleChange(field, value) {
    this.setState({ [`my_${field}`]: value });
}
```